# How to get cursor to right edge of an EditText that has been programmatically edited since user put data into it?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have 5 `EditText` fields. Wherever the cursor is positioned in the first 3 only before getting output from a dialog, it stays in the *same* position after the user gets output from a dialog. That's good.

But for the last 2, the cursor is always positioned **before** the first digit after the dialog. That's **not** good.

The reason for this is that I always edit the last two since they could contain digits that are also in the third field and that's illogical (on the user's part).

I don't care if the cursor stays where the user had left it in those 2 fields, but I would like to have it positioned at the right edge of the field after I edit them.

I was hoping something easy, like what's below, would put the cursor at the right edge of the fields, but no.

```
    String sss;
    sss = exclude.getText().toString();
    exclude.setText("");
    exclude.setText(sss);
```

Adding `.requestFocus()` doesn't do it either.

Nor does `.setGravity(View.FOCUS_RIGHT)`.

Cursor is always at left edge of field.

Any thoughts about how to get cursor to right edge of a field that has been programmatically edited since user put data into it?

*** EDIT #3 after reading Answer below *** This DOES do it (if you put it in a logical place!!):

```
    exclude.setSelection(exclude.getText().length());
```

*** EDIT #4 *** This is the same as the above and also DOES do it.

```
    exclude.setSelection(exclude.getText().toString().length());
```

Comment: I saw that you updated your question after my answer. Could you try and check the value of `exclude.getText().length()` and see what you're getting? You should get a positive number in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection(int)). The best way to move the cursor at the end of the EditText right most position is using

```
mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
```

Comment: Something wacky is going on... I'm not getting any `Log` output to provide those numbers you asked for.... I'm going to have to call it a day. I'll try your suggestions--they make perfect sense--later tonight or tomorrow. Thank you for helping. I'll get it, with your help, I'm fairly sure.

Comment: Sure. You should check what's the value of `mEditText.getText().length()`. It should be a positive non-zero number. If its not, that means something else is going wrong. Also make sure that you are calling the above code, only after you programmatically set the text to the EditText.

Comment: Of course what you suggested (and what I had already tried but said it failed) WORKS. I had put the statement in a part of the code that wasn't executing after the edit!! (Gah!!) THANK YOU for waking me up!